# Java Generics run-time instantiation

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have my generic interface:

```
public interface myGenericInterface<T> {...}
```

And I have a class retrieved this way:

```
Class<?> myClass = Class.forName("myClassName");
```

I would like to be able to instantiate something like this:

```
myGenericInterface<myClass> mySubType ...
```

It's not working of course. Is there a way of doing something like that?

UPDATE:

Well, since generics is relevant to compile-time  I guess it won't work with reflection style code. So no good can come out of that.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. Could you expand on your description of your ultimate goal? Perhaps a full code fragment showing what you wish you were able to do?

Comment: Do you mean `myGenericInterface<SomeType> mySubType = (myGenericInterface<SomeType>) myClass.newInstance();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics are a **compile-time** feature that helps to avoid programming errors, so what you are trying to do makes no sense, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare object with generics in class field then Field reflection object from this class keeps what kind of generic was declared.

```
static class ClassA {
    public List<String> field = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Field field = ClassA.class.getField("field");
    Class<?> genericType = getGenericType(field);
    System.out.println(genericType);
}

private static Class<?> getGenericType(Field field) {
    final Type type0 = field.getGenericType();
    if (type0 instanceof ParameterizedType) {
        final Type type = ((ParameterizedType) type0).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        if (type instanceof Class<?>) {
            return (Class<?>) type;
        }
        // miss code for method arguments
    }
    return Object.class;
}
```

Code prints `class java.lang.String` and can be useful in your case but basically raw Class object doesn't carry generics information - as generics information are used only on compile time and not runtime time.